# How to save multiple partition's Kafka offset by own self when use spark-streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I use spark-streaming to read kafka data,and process every line

I use below to create a streaming :

```
lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jssc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics,kafkaParams)
    );
```

and then I use this code to process data from kafka

```
    lines.foreachRDD((JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rdd) -> {
          OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
          OffsetRange[] range = new OffsetRange[1];
          range[0] = o;

          rdd.foreachPartition((Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> partitionOfRecords) -> {
          // get kafka offset
          OffsetRange o = offsetRanges[TaskContext.get().partitionId()];
          // to cache line data
          List<String> jsonData = new ArrayList<>();
          // to read all line data
          while (partitionOfRecords.hasNext()) {
                ConsumerRecord<String, String> line = partitionOfRecords.next();
                jsonData.add(line.value());
          }
          // TODO  do my own bussiness from jsonData
          .......
          //  HOW can I commit kafka Offset Here??
          // this is a method to commit offset 
          ((CanCommitOffsets) lines.inputDStream()).commitAsync(range) 
      });
    });
```

And I have try many times, I found it have some problem:

1. How does it work if my data process success when other partition failed? it means all my data process should come back? Because kafka offset has commit;
2. I have run this code, then I found it really execute commit operate is when the next time this rdd executor run,it means if the progress oom or be killed , the next time some data I read from Kafka will double ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does it work if my data process success when other partition
>   failed? it means all my data process should come back? Because kafka
>   offset has commit

If a particular task fails, Spark will attempt to re-execute it in place according to the `spark.task.maxFailures` setting. If the number has passed, the entire job will fail. You need to make sure that if the part before `commitAsync` fails, you don't commit offsets.

> I have run this code, then I found it really execute commit operate is
>   when the next time this rdd executor run,it means if the progress oom
>   or be killed , the next time some data I read from Kafka will double ?

Yes. If the job is killed before the next batch iteration, Spark will attempt to re-read data that's already been processed.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer.So how I can do I can only read data once? Because I don't want use transaction for each time.

Comment: @DreamHeaven You'll need to store offsets yourself, and reload them on recover. I suggest you take a look at Structured Streaming which gives you better streaming semantics.

Comment: For the case mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684667/spark-structured-streaming-with-rabbitmq-source), if one node consumes messages with offset 1 & 3, and the other node consumes 2, what will happen if the first node succeeds but the second fails? I mean, the commits are called globally or locally? Will it commit for 3? If so, what would happen to 2?