# Spark Structured Streaming with RabbitMQ source

Tags: java, apache-spark, rabbitmq, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write a custom receiver for `Structured Streaming` that will consume messages from `RabbitMQ`.
`Spark` [recently released](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/02/28/introducing-apache-spark-2-3.html) DataSource V2 API, which seems very promising. Since it abstracts away many details, I want to use this API for the sake of both simplicity and performance. However, since it's quite new, there are not many sources available. I need some clarification from experienced `Spark` guys, since they will grasp the key points easier. Here we go:

My starting point is the blog post series, with the first part [here](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/spark-datasource-v2-part-1/). It shows how to implement a data source, without streaming capability. To make a streaming source, I slightly changed them, since I need to implement [MicroBatchReadSupport](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/MicroBatchReadSupport.html) instead of (or in addition to) [DataSourceV2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/DataSourceV2.html).

To be efficient, it's wise to have multiple spark executors consuming `RabbitMQ` concurrently, i.e. from the same queue. If I'm not confused, every partition of the input -in `Spark`'s terminology- corresponds to a consumer from the queue -in `RabbitMQ` terminology. Thus, we need to have multiple partitions for the input stream, right?

Similar with [part 4 of the series](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/spark-datasource-v2-part-4/), I implemented [MicroBatchReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/reader/streaming/MicroBatchReader.html) as follows:

```
@Override
public List<DataReaderFactory<Row>> createDataReaderFactories() {
    int partition = options.getInt(RMQ.PARTITICN, 5);
    List<DataReaderFactory<Row>> factories = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < partition; i++) {
        factories.add(new RMQDataReaderFactory(options));
    }
    return factories;
}
```

I am returning a list of factories, and hope that every instance in the list will be used to create a reader, which will be also a consumer. Is that approach correct?

I want my reciever to be reliable, i.e. after every processed message (or at least written to chekpoint directory for further processing), I need to ack it back to `RabbitMQ`. The problem starts after here: these factories are created at the driver, and the actual reading process takes place at executors through [DataReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/reader/DataReader.html)s. However, the [commit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/reader/streaming/MicroBatchReader.html#commit-org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.reader.streaming.Offset-) method is a part of `MicroBatchReader`, not `DataReader`. Since I have many `DataReader`s per `MicroBatchReader`, how should I ack these messages back to `RabbitMQ`? Or should I ack when the [next](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/reader/DataReader.html#next--) method is called on `DataReader`? Is it safe? If so, what is the purpose of `commit` function then?

<del>**CLARIFICATION:**</del> **OBFUSCATION:** The link provided in the answer about the renaming of some classes/functions (in addition to the explanations there) made everything <del>**much more clear**</del> **worse than ever**. Quoting from [there](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/62d01391fee77eedd75b4e3f475ede8b9f0df0c2):

> Renames:
>
> - `DataReaderFactory` to `InputPartition`
> - `DataReader` to `InputPartitionReader`
>
> ...
>
> `InputPartition`'s purpose is to manage the lifecycle of the
>   associated reader, which is now called `InputPartitionReader`, with an
>   explicit create operation to mirror the close operation. This was no
>   longer clear from the API because `DataReaderFactory` appeared to be more
>   generic than it is and it isn't clear why a set of them is produced for
>   a read.

**EDIT:** However, the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/reader/DataReaderFactory.html) clearly say that "the reader factory will be serialized and sent to executors, then the data reader will be created on executors and do the actual reading."

To make the consumer reliable, I have to ACK for a particular message only after it is committed at Spark side. [Note that](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Is-DeliveryTag-unique-for-every-rabbitmq-message-td36226.html) the messages have to be ACKed on the same connection that it has been delivered through, but commit function is called at driver node. How can I commit at the worker/executor node?

Comment: reading operations happening in driver or executor for you ?

Comment: They are happening at executor. When I have time, I will write an extended answer for this question, but short to say, it is impossible to use V2 API with RabbitMQ, due to some design mismatches.

Comment: I have implemented IBM MQ source in DataSourceV1, but the problem is reading happening in Driver. If possible, can you share your code?

Comment: @PadmanabhanVijendran The code is quite complex, but how do you know that it is at the driver? You may be running a master and a worker at the same node?

Comment: I can see the logs (Sysouts for testing) in the Application master logs and also there will be no jobs till my driver finishes reading from MQ. I might implemented wrongly. Thats why asked your help.

Comment: @ram How you handled the offset implementation ? Can you help me with your approach ?

Answer (score 0):

<del>> I am returning a list of factories, and hope that every instance in the list will be used to create a reader, which will be also a consumer. Is that approach correct?


The source [socket][1] source implementation has one thread pushing messages into the internal ListBuffer. In other words, there is one consumer (the thread) filling up the internal ListBuffer which is **then** divided up into partitions by `planInputPartitions`( `createDataReaderFactories` got [renamed][2] to `planInputPartitions`).


Also, according to the Javadoc of [MicroBatchReadSupport][3]


> The execution engine will create a micro-batch reader at the start of a streaming query, alternate calls to setOffsetRange and createDataReaderFactories for each batch to process, and then call stop() when the execution is complete. Note that a single query may have multiple executions due to restart or failure recovery.


In other words, the `createDataReaderFactories` should be called **multiple** times, which to my understanding suggests that each `DataReader` is responsible for a static input partition, which implies that the DataReader shouldn't be a consumer.



----------


> However, the commit method is a part of MicroBatchReader, not DataReader ... If so, what is the purpose of commit function then?


Perhaps part of the rationale for the commit function is to prevent the internal buffer of the MicroBatchReader from getting to big. By committing an Offset, you can effectively remove elements less than the Offset from the buffer as you are making a commitment to not process them anymore. You can see this happening in the socket source code with `batches.trimStart(offsetDiff)`</del>

---

<del>I'm unsure about implementing a reliable receiver, so I hope a more experienced Spark guy comes around and grabs your question as I'm interested too!

Hope this helps!</del>

**EDIT**

I had only studied the [socket](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/sources/socket.scala), and [wiki-edit](https://github.com/hienluu/wikiedit-streaming) sources. These sources are not production ready, which is something that the question was was not looking for. Instead, the [kafka](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala) source is the better starting point which has, unlike the aforementioned sources, multiple consumers like the author was looking for.

However, perhaps if you're looking for unreliable sources, the socket and wikiedit sources above provide a less complicated solution.

Comment: Quoting from [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/reader/DataReaderFactory.html):  "Note that, the reader factory will be serialized and sent to executors, then the data reader will be created on executors and do the actual reading." Also [preferredLocations()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/reader/DataReaderFactory.html#preferredLocations--) implies that each reader should be a consumer itself.

Comment: In addition, probably you have found the reason why socket source is not suggested to be used at production environments.

Comment: I took a quick scan at the [kafka source implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala) which should be production ready and it does seem like you are correct that each DataReader could be a consumer.

Comment: According to the PR "One InputPartition is a specific partition of the data to be read". I guess because I only studied the socket and the ones written by hienluu, I was under the impression that the partitions referred to the internal buffers maintained. Instead it seems like the specific partitions could refer directly to the consumer as in the kafka source. Thanks for making me aware of this! :) I really wish there were official guides on how to write these sources!

Comment: Also concerning "Note that, the reader factory will be serialized and sent to executors, then the data reader will be created on executors and do the actual reading." The socket implementation does abide by this -- just a static portion of the data buffer is serialized as a part of the the factory and read.